# Why result of the inbuild chrome lighthouse and chrome plugin lighthouse differs variably in a big way?

Tags: plugins, performance-testing, lighthouse, web-testing

i'm testing a page performance score for a client using both inbuild chrome lighthouse and chrome plugin lighthouse, the results differs in a big way.

For desktop, Chrome inbuild lighthouse shows high performance score that is between 85 - 99 while chrome plugin lighthouse shows around 60 - 70, for mobile its worse.

The first image below is chrome plugin lighthouse test results

The second image below is inbuild chrome lighthouse test results

[image: chrome plugin lighthouse test results]

[image: inbuild chrome lighthouse test results]

i did chatgpt and google search, what's one point that keeps repeating is chrome lighthouse plugin is run from a different server, while inbuild chrome lighthouse is run from my device.

Can you anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Assuming "chrome plugin lighthouse" is the [Lighthouse extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lighthouse/blipmdconlkpinefehnmjammfjpmpbjk) the web store says it's from 2019 and it's fully integrated now so why do you use it instead of the built-in one?

Comment: but using pagespeed insights, the results are also varies, can you explain why?

Comment: @mockingbird - Why are you asking these questions here? Wouldn't it make more sense to ask them on Lighthouse's Github page? I'd be surprised if anyone here could do more than speculate what the answers might be.